# Getting all anchors from a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an array containing all the anchor links in a string. For example, if I have a string like the following

```
<a href="http://google.it>Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com>Google 2</a>
```

It should return me an array of two elements containing

> http://google.it
>
> http://google.com

My string is obtained from a textarea, so I tried

```
var html = $("textarea[name=html]").val();
var links = $(html).find('a').attr('href');
console.log(links);
```

However, only one link (presumably the first one in the string) is showing up. I know I might need to loop through all the anchors in the string, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr()` only returns the first match, you have to map the attributes back

```
var arr = $('<div />', {html:html}).find('a').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
}).get()

var str = arr.join(','); // if you need a string
```

Comment: My I ask what is the `'<div />'` for?

Comment: @wiredmark - it's a parent container, in case you have elements that aren't descendants of other elements, as `find` only finds descendants.

Answer (score 4):

`.attr()` will return just the first element attribute try to iterate all the elements and store the attribute in array :

```js
var links = [];

$('body').find('a').each(function(){
  links.push( $(this).attr('href') );
})

console.log(links);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://google.it">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Google 2</a>
```